# Angular element, $http.get

Tags: angularjs

I have a script that queries off to my server to obtain various values.  In the UI - there's a JQuery slider input where the user can change one of the values - which I'd like to have re-query the server/PHP script.

Here's what I have.

```
    var app = angular.module("myServices", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("servicesCntrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://myservice.com/scripts.php?dist="+28)
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.contractors;});
});


function updateVal() {
    var scope = angular.element($("#batch")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function($http){
        $http.get("http://myservice.com/scripts.php?dist="+28)
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.contractors;});
    })
}
```

The controller works fine - and grabs the values as expected.  The updateVal script (which is called on the onChange event) gets hung up saying $http.get is not a function.

What am I missing?  :)  Thanks in advance!

---edit

Okay - I made a couple of modifications - but still don't have it.  Sorry - I'm pretty new to angular :)

Here's what I have now.  The slider script - and the angular.

```
<div class="ui-field-contain" data-controltype="slider">
                <label for="slider1">
                    Adjust Distance
                </label>
                <input id="slider1" type="range" name="slider" value="5" min="0" max="50"
                data-highlight="false" onchange="updateVals()">
            </div>
```

and the angular

```
app.controller("servicesCntrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.updateVals = function () {
        console.log("Booyah");
    }
    $http.get("http://example.com/scripts.php?dist="+28)
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.contractors;});
});
```

--- Edit 3 -- Thanks for the help :)

slider with ng-model - and ng-change

```
<div class="ui-field-contain" data-controltype="slider">
                <label for="slider1">
                    Adjust Distance
                </label>
                <input id="slider1" type="range" name="slider" value="5" min="0" max="50"
                data-highlight="false" ng-model="myslider" ng-change="updateVals">
            </div>
```

and angular

something's still missing..

```
app.controller("servicesCntrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.updateVals = function () {
        console.log("Booyah");
    }
    $http.get("http://example.com/scripts.php?dist="+28)
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.contractors;});
});
```

Comment: why is updateVal outside the controller? It doesnt have access to $http

Answer (score 1):

Your `updateVal()` function is outside the controller where you injected the `$http` service so you have no access to it. Move the `updateVal` function into your controller.

Comment: onChange isn't a ng attribute. Try surrounding the function with {{}}

Comment: I originally tried using a ng-change - but while that didn't error out - it did absolutely nothing.  I figured maybe the jquery was conflicting with it

Comment: "The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model."

You need to specify ng-model if you want it to work.

A working example with a range input is here http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/working-with-ng-model-and-input-type-range/949